# Lua module - how to not include Lua core?

Tags: gcc, lua, mingw, mingw-w64

I need to build [this Lua module](https://github.com/starwing/luautf8) and to be able to use it in another application that already has Lua core included. Module will be loaded via 'require'.

I'm using MinGW x64 on Windows 10. I successfully built Lua 5.2 with it, extracted `lua.dll` file and renamed it into `liblua.dll.a`.
Then I built the module using following Makefile:

```
CC = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
LUA_INCDIR=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include

utf8.dll: lutf8lib.o
  $(CC) -m64 -O -shared -fpic lutf8lib.c -o utf8.dll -llua

lutf8lib.o: lutf8lib.c
  $(CC) -O2 -fpic -c -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL lutf8lib.c -I$(LUA_INCDIR)
```

The problem is file size, it's 420kb and it definetely includes Lua core (I got 'multiple VMs' error). I need to build the module without including the core.

Previously I installed usual MinGW (x86) and used following Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
LUA_INCDIR=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include
utf8.dll: lutf8lib.o
    $(CC) -m32 -shared lutf8lib.c -o utf8.dll -llua

lutf8lib.o: lutf8lib.c
    $(CC) -fPIC -c lutf8lib.c -I$(LUA_INCDIR)
```

And got 97kb file without Lua core. Unfortunately I specifically need x64 file.

UPD: I tried to build the same module using MSVC, but it seems that IDE changes `luaopen_utf8` function name. If I'll add this to fix it:

```
int __declspec(dllexport)
```

IDE will include Lua core VM into DLL file. Again.